# Apps script to match sheet name that contains an ID and make it visible

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, string-matching

I am trying to modify this apps script to be able to search for a sheet that contains a specific ID (e.g 123), and make that sheet visible/activated, if the sheet is named `abc123def`.

The below code works well if I enter the full name of the sheet `abc123def`, but I'd like to enter only a part of the sheet-name, the ID, in this case `123`.

This works for me in PowerShell:

```
$match = "123"
$text = Get-Content -Path $fulltext | Select-String -Pattern $match
$text | Out-File -FilePath $output
```

But I am not sure how to make a similar match for below Apps Script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuItems=[{name: 'Go To Tab', functionName: 'goToTab'} ];
  ss.addMenu('Script', menuItems);
};

function goToTab() {
  var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter Tab Name:','',Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name).activate();
  }
  catch(e) {
    Browser.msgBox('Sheet named: "' + name + '" does not exists!');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuItems = [{
        name: 'Go To Tab',
        functionName: 'goToTab'
    }];
    ss.addMenu('Script', menuItems);
};

function goToTab() {
    var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter Tab Name:', '', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (name) {
        try {
            //create a regex out of "name"
            regexp = new RegExp(name, 'g');
            //get all the sheets
            var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
            //go through all the sheets
            for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
                //if sheet name matches the user entry then activate and go out of the loop
                if (sheets[i].getName().match(regexp)) {
                    sheets[i].activate();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            Browser.msgBox('Sheet named: "' + name + '" does not exists!');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)